# Break line in description method not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am triyng to ovveride description method. And I wold line the string to have a line break. But `/n` and `/r` do not work.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some text: \r some more text - %@",@"more text"];
}
```

and I triyed this:

```
- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some text: \n some more text - %@",@"more text"];
}
```

Comment: return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some text: \n some more text - more text"];
 No need to use a placeholder for a constant string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you have tried should really work. Since its not working in your case, you can try this:

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"some text: \r\n some more text - %@",@"more text"] isHTML:YES];
```

Should work .